# MVC Architecture from Development to Production

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to gain a better understanding of MVC architecture. I write both front end and back end web applications using LAMP stack. I don't use any frameworks yet. I code in Notepad++ and use WinSCP for file transfer (Putty for terminal). All of the server side coding is done in PHP.

Based on the reading I've done, this is my best guess on how MVC's files are structured:

```
+ -- Project1
|    + -- models
|    |    + -- model.php
|    + -- views
|    |    + -- view.php
|    + -- controllers
|    |    + -- controller.php
+ -- Project2
|    + -- models
|    |    + -- model.php
|    + -- views
|    |    + -- view.php
|    + -- controllers
|    |    + -- controller.php
```

So, while there are a lot of articles and blogs about what models, views, and controllers are, I haven't seen anything about how to set this up past what I've gathered above.

I have no idea how this becomes integrated in relation to my public folder on my server. Here is my guess, assuming that `/var/www/html/` is my public directory.

```
+ -- var
|    + -- www
|    |    + -- html
|    |    |    + -- my-application-1.php
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    + -- my-application-2.php
|    |    + -- Project1
|    |    |    + -- models
|    |    |    |    + -- model.php
|    |    |    + -- views
|    |    |    |    + -- view.php
|    |    |    + -- controllers
|    |    |    |    + -- controller.php
|    |    + -- Project2
|    |    |    + -- models
|    |    |    |    + -- model.php
|    |    |    + -- views
|    |    |    |    + -- view.php
|    |    |    + -- controllers
|    |    |    |    + -- controller.php
```

I am assuming based on what I've read (maybe I'm wrong) that people put their entire project "behind" their public folder. I am also assuming that you take your final application file (`my-application1.php` or `my-application-2.php`), put it in your public folder for people on the internet to use, and reference (php's `include`/`require`) your models, views and controllers from that application file. I've never referenced files behind my public file, but I'm assuming a lot here.

Can someone verify any of this for me? How is this supposed to be set up in relation to the rest of my linux server? Is there anything I am assuming that is incorrect that you'd care to correct?

I am trying to gain a good understanding of this before I pick up any frameworks (probably leaning toward Zend, Laravel, or CakePHP). I have read that frameworks help with this, but I currently don't have the resources to set up a framework and I would like to gain a full understanding of this before trying to pitch this to my team.

Comment: If you're looking at this purely from the file structuring scheme (which web "MVC" is mostly about these days), then yes, that's a practical approach. If two projects share enough backend or handler logic, you could also just alternate between `template1/` and `template2/` dirs (AKA "views", lol). -- Is your main question about how to move these structures below the vhost root path? That's often accomplished with just e.g. `include_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/../lib/bootstrap.php");` or a framework base path, or lazy autoloaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying in your question that you don't have the resources to set up a framework but yet you have to resources to build one from scratch without even having the slightest idea what you're doing?

Believe me, **you don't want to do it yourself**. At the very least, you should first try some existing framework like symfony2 or zf2 or whatever you like.

When you'll become familiar with some of these and understand how they work, you will be able to create your own and give up in front of the tons of work it require.

Anyway, to answer the question, here's how zend framework 1 is structured

```
project
|-- application
|   |-- Bootstrap.php
|   |-- configs
|   |   `-- application.ini
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- ErrorController.php
|   |   `-- IndexController.php
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|       |-- helpers
|       `-- scripts
|           |-- error
|           |   `-- error.phtml
|           `-- index
|               `-- index.phtml
|-- library
|-- public
|   |-- .htaccess
|   `-- index.php
```

With this framework, you would setup your web root to `/path/to/project/public`.
As you can see, none of the application code is directly accessible from the web. All incoming requests come throught the index.php where all the magic is.

If you're interested in knowing what the magic really is, all the php web framework are open source so feel free to check it out for yourself :

[ZF2 on github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2)

[Sf2 on guthub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony)

Comment: I guess that another assumption that I had was that people actually set this up and do this without a framework. Are you saying that almost no one does this on their own, and that experience with MVC architecture is derived from using frameworks?

Comment: Yes I am. Most small to medium companies will use a framework to get the job done. I think this is true for every languages, not only for php. It can be interesting to write your own mvc framework if you have some **very specific reasons** but otherwise it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

It's very dependant on the framework you choose to use, but the general idea is that the actual source directory is NOT stored in the web root. I use `/web/projects` on my deployments, then symlinking the public folder out to the `htdocs`

```
> cd /var/www/html
> ln -s /web/projects/myProject/public myproject
```

You'll then usually have an `index.php` file in the public file that kicks things off. There's also usually a `.htaccess` file that intercepts all requests and points them at that file.

Best option is to choose a framework (Laravel and Symfony are excellent options) and follow the getting started guides.